# how to avoid symfony 4 for creating default folders in src

Tags: symfony, composer-php

How I can avoid creating folders like `Controller`, `Entity` and so on inside of `src` directory when I'm running `composer install` as I'm using different folder structure in my application and it's annoying to delete that folders each time I run `composer install` by the first time on some machine

Comment: Are you sure composer install is creating these directories?  Maybe check to see if they are coming from your source code repository.  composer create-project will create them but I'm pretty sure install does not since I use a different structure myself and have never encountered this problem during deployment.

Comment: in my repo I have different directories structure: Application, Domain, Interfaces, Infrastructure. But when I run `composer install` it creating Controller, Entity, Repository and Migration folders alongside

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have a good test case for now so I'll take your word for it.  You can always remove the post-install-cmd section from composer.json though that may cause more harm than good.

Comment: This is related to symfony/framework-bundle flex setup for example. 

https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/manifest.json#L8

Answer (score 2):

These folders are created by different flex recipes ONCE.

Example for  symfony/framework-bundle:
https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/manifest.json#L8

After successful installation these changes are tracked into symfony.lock file.

Do you have that file? It needs to be added to VCS like composer.json/composer.lock

Then delete the unneeded folders from filesystem. They should not be created again.

Source: 
https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/419

Comment: You are right I did not notice that new symfony hs symfony.lock file, thanks

Comment: Ah yes.  The lock file.  That explains why I never saw this happening.